# How to deal with pipes stuck to the wall?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, pipe-fitting

I need to add a second water outlet to a pipe :

[image]

I bought a T, but the pipe is very close to the wall, so I cannot screw the tee :

[image]

I think the pipe is not only screwed to the wall by the visible screws (oval red in the picture) but also there is probably some glue (red arrow):

[image]

What is the right process in that case ?

Should I cut through the glue with a knife and unscrew the screws, install the T, and re-install everything? That seems a little complicated, and also, I was unable to unscrew the screws (old screws).

So I thought about installing the T at the bottom of the flexible pipe:

[image]

What is the right procedure here? What would a good plumber do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a tee like this one where the upstream connector is a female threaded nut just like the one currently on the tube connected to your valve.  This is more like a 3/8 "splitter" than a tee, and that's what you want.

With this you can turn the nut instead of the whole tee.

[image: https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-3-8-in-x-3-8-in-x-3-8-in-Compression-x-Compression-Brass-T-Fitting-CT2-666X-P/202495893?mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-BNG-D26P-026_001_PIPE_FITTING-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-2023&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-BNG-D26P-026_001_PIPE_FITTING-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-2023-71700000106036633-58700008262676761-92700075065924088&gclid=990578699e561e2611a31ce45e0b3007&gclsrc=3p.ds&msclkid=990578699e561e2611a31ce45e0b3007]

Answer (score 1):

That's not really a flex pipe, but just a section of bent/shaped copper pipe or tubing.  In any case, I would add the T someplace along that copper run.

It looks like that section of copper is attached to the top & bottom pieces of pipes with compression fittings (though it's hard to say for sure from the pictures), and so should be relatively easy to remove.  After turning off the water, you can cut the pipe and remove it in two sections.

But, you might have difficulty installing the new copper pipes as there may not be enough play to slide the new pipes into the female part of the fittings in order to make the compression joints.  You may have to fiddle around with it a bit.